# queryParams in Angular does not seem to bind to the actual query paramerters

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I feel like this may be a stupid mistake. However, could anyone kindly point out where my code is going wrong? The problem is that I have `[queryParams] = "{allowEdit: server.id == 3 ? 1 : 0}"` and when in `edit-server component`, I subscribe to the queryparams, but the params object is empty for some reason? Why is it empty and how can I add `allowEdit` to it? It may have to do with an incorrect path? I'll provide details about relevant paths instead.

Here's my code:

ServerS Template

```html
  <!-- 
          Routerlink points to the server component NOT 'edit-server' component, perhaps 
          this is why queryParams 
          does not work on 'edit-server'
        -->
      <a
        [routerLink] = "['/servers', server.id]"
        [queryParams] = "{allowEdit: server.id == 3 ? 1 : 0}"
        href="#"
        class="list-group-item"
        *ngFor="let server of servers">
        {{ server.name }}
      </a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Server Template:

```html
<h5>{{ server.name }}</h5>
<p>Server status is {{ server.status }}</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit()">Edit Server</button>
```

Server TS:

```js
export class ServerComponent implements OnInit {
  server: {id: number, name: string, status: string};
  id: number

  constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id']
    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id)
  
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.server = this.serversService.getServer(this.id)

    })

  }

  onEdit() {
    this.router.navigate(['edit'], {relativeTo: this.route})
  }

}
```

Edit Server TS:

```js
export class EditServerComponent implements OnInit {
  server: {id: number, name: string, status: string};
  serverName = '';
  serverStatus = '';
  allowEdit: boolean

  constructor(private serversService: ServersService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.snapshot.queryParams
    this.route.snapshot.fragment
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      console.log(params['allowEdit']) // for some reason, params['allowEdit'] gives us undefined
      this.allowEdit = params['allowEdit'] == 1 ? true : false
    })
    this.route.fragment.subscribe((params: string) => {
    
    })
    //
    this.server = this.serversService.getServer(1);
    this.serverName = this.server.name;
    this.serverStatus = this.server.status;
  }
}
```

Note, some code might be blocks of code might be irrelevant, but in case it helps you that's good. If you want any more blocks of code, please let me know. Here's my folder structure and AppModule paths.

App Module:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [ {
      path: 'users/:id/:name',
      component: UserComponent
    }]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },

  // The ones below are the important ones
  {
    path: 'servers',
    component: ServersComponent,
    children: [  {
      path: ':id/edit',
      component: EditServerComponent
    },
    {
      path: ':id',
      component: ServerComponent
    }]
  },
  
]
```

Relevant Folder structure

[image: - Server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed right: `allowEdit` is only sent to the route `servers/:id`

If you want to access it from the `servers/:id/edit` component you have to declare it as a child of the `servers/:id` route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // other routes
  {
    path: 'servers',
    component: ServersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ServerComponent
        children: [
          {
            path: 'edit',
            component: EditServerComponent
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

and in the EditServerComponent you have to access the data through the parent route:
`this.route.parent.queryParams.subscribe(...)`